# Does a Firbolg lose their invisibility granted by the Hidden Step trait if a creature they summon attacks or deals damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, summoning, firbolg

The description of the [firbolg trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/firbolg#FirbolgTraits) Hidden Step states (VGtM, p. 107):

> As a bonus action, you can magically turn invisible until the start of your next turn or until you attack, make a damage roll, or force someone to make a saving throw. Once you use this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

If you summon a creature and command it to attack and deal damage for you, does that count as you making an attack/damage roll, and therefore breaking your invisibility?

Or does the fact that your summon is its own creature mean that you didn't make any rolls that would break your invisibility (though your summon did, while having no invisibility)?

Comment: Related: [Can my Warlock attack with their familiar and remain invisible?](/questions/147058), [What counts as an attack?](/questions/71245)

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from "make a damage roll" referring to an out-of-character action performed by the player, and the fact that the player may in fact be rolling damage for the creatures summoned by their character. I think the choice of wording in the ability is a bit unfortunate, not least because it's unclear whether it includes abilities that deal a flat amount of damage without rolling dice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You and a creature you summon are different creatures.

Hidden Step stipulates that it ends if *you* do any of the things:

> or until **you** attack, make a damage roll, or force someone to make a saving throw.

Since a creature you summon is a creature that is not you, your invisibility does not end if the creature does one of the things.