# Interaction between Spirit Shroud and Animate Objects. Does animate Objects count as one of your attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack

[Animate Object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-objects) Says:

> As a bonus action, you can mentally command any creature you made with this spell if the creature is within 500 feet of you.

This command can be an attack.   In effect you are using your bonus action to indirectly attack.

[Spirit Shroud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-shroud) Says:

> any attack you make deals 1d8 extra damage when you hit a creature within 10 feet of you.

If I command animated objects attack within the 10' limit of spirit shroud at your direction, do they benefit from spirt shrouds extra damage?

In this case I am hung up on the language.  I am making the attack, without me there would be no attack.  But it might be more literal?

Comment: Related, kinda: "[What is the attacker for Spiritual Weapon? The caster or the weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/168947)" and "[Does a Firbolg lose their invisibility granted by the Hidden Step trait if a creature they summon attacks or deals damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/182072)" and "[Can my Warlock attack with their familiar and remain invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147058)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### *You* are not attacking, the object is.

Animate Objects specifically states:

> Each target animates and **becomes a creature** under your control...
>
> [...]
>
> If *you command an object to attack*, **it** can make a single melee attack against a creature within 5 feet of it. **It makes a slam attack** [...]

You may be commanding the animated object to attack but it is its own entity, its own creature so *you* are not the one making the attack.

Page 194 of the PHB also states:

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: *if **you're** making an attack roll, you're making an attack.*

**You** are not making an attack roll, the animated object is, so **you** are not making an attack.

Therefore Spirit Shroud doesn't apply to the attack made by the animated object.

Comment: But I am using my bonus action to cause the attack.

Comment: What about summon fey?  It uses my spell attack modifier to attack.    Same as spiritual weapon..

Comment: @SamLacrumb You aren't using your bonus action to cause the attack, you are using your bonus action to give orders. The actual attack for the animated objects doesn't happen on your turn.

Comment: And even if the attack _did_ happen on your turn, it is explicit that **the object** is making the attack, not **you**.

Comment: @SamLacrumb it's probably out of the range of this question. But spiritual weapon is worded very differently and YOU make the attack roll. While the summon spell doesn't explicitely says it the same way. But says that YOU only give order and the summon is a different creature.

Comment: It's really annoying that every spell is worded slightly differently and every spell works slightly differently. But that's 5e for ya.